# java.lang.NullPointerException ; when the connector works in the project

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm doing a small project with screenplay and selenium, and it works fine up to the point of clicking on a popup and loading a NullPointerException.

```
public class CreateUser implements Task {

    private String userName;
    private String passWord;

    public CreateUser(String userName, String passWord) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.passWord = passWord;
    }

    @Override
    public <T extends Actor> void performAs(T actor) {
        actor.attemptsTo(
                WaitUntil.the(SingUpPage.TEXTBOX_USERNAME, isVisible()).forNoMoreThan(10).seconds(),
                Enter.theValue(userName).into(SingUpPage.TEXTBOX_USERNAME),
                Enter.theValue(passWord).into(SingUpPage.TEXTBOX_PASSW),
                Click.on(SingUpPage.BTN_SINGUP)
        );
        WaitDriver.TwoSecond();
        Alert alert = HandDriver.getDriver().switchTo().alert();
        alert.accept();
    }

    public static CreateUser createUser(String userName, String passWord){
        return new CreateUser(userName,passWord);
    }
}
```

```
New user - Successful scenario in the creation of a user on the page
---------------------------------------------------------------
[Test worker] ERROR  -     Test failed at step: When Enter the new "AB123" and "ab123"
[Test worker] ERROR  -     

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at co.com.demoblaze.tasks.CreateUser.performAs(CreateUser.java:35)
    at net.serenitybdd.screenplay.Actor.performTask(Actor.java:283)
    at net.serenitybdd.screenplay.Actor.perform(Actor.java:262)
    at net.serenitybdd.screenplay.Actor.performWithoutReporting(Actor.java:246)
    at net.serenitybdd.screenplay.Actor.attemptsTo(Actor.java:201)
    at net.serenitybdd.screenplay.Actor.attemptsTo(Actor.java:210)
    at co.com.demoblaze.stepDefenitions.EventUserSingUpStep.enterTheNewAnd(EventUserSingUpStep.java:30)
    at ✽.Enter the new "AB123" and "ab123"(file:///C:/Users/daniel.moralesro_pra/Documents/Proyecto_intellij/com.demoblaze.automatizacion/src/test/resources/features/header/userEvent.feature:9)
```

I do not understand why it gives null if the connector works but with the alert it does not work, please can you guide me what I am doing wrong.

Alert alert = HandDriver.getDriver().switchTo().alert(); this is the line that loads null